# Async / Multi Threading Pillow Image Grab for 60fps

Tags: python, opencv, asynchronous, python-imaging-library

#### What I'm trying to do.

Currently I am using `PIL` too grab a screen shot of my desktop and display the image in a constant loop. This produces a video like effect of screenshots. My intent is analyze each image taken with `opencv` and display the manipulated results.

#### What I'm currently doing.

At the moment I have a loop with a 1 millisecond delay taking a screenshot and then displaying it through `opencv`. Unfortunately grabbing and analyzing the image takes a while and produces the effect I am looking for, but at a lowered frame rate as it takes longer than a millisecond to grab the screenshot and display it.

#### What I'm looking for.

I'm hoping to asynchronously run this process so that concurrently I can get a smoother frame rate. Unfortunately when I attempt to use `Process` or `threading`on my function I get a warning saying that the action must be taken from the main thread.

#### How may I be able to make the bellow code async/threaded?

```
def getImage(bbox):
    while True:
        #Grab pil image
        pil_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3])).convert('RGB')

        #conver the image to something opencv can use
        image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(pil_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        #show the image
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

        #wait a millisecond so that the image displays
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

#### Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!'
```

Comment: can you share the error you encountered when applying Process / Threads?

Comment: @dcwhcdhw I just included the error in the question.